# Filter vim's quickfix window per file

Tags: vim, neovim, vim-quickfix

I'm using the cquery language server in my Neovim instance. In conjunction with the Languageclient-neovim plugin. This automatically also checks the code for errors in the file that I'm working. However, this also means it checks all the files in my workspace.

I was wondering if there was a possibility to **only** show errors that are specific to the file that I am working in. See the example below:

[image: Example]

I'm working in the file `src/bag_rotation.cpp` and I only want to filter the quickfix window to only show errors from that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, I wrote a vim plugin, can do ":Keep" and ":Reject" on quickfix window (among other things).

https://github.com/romainl/vim-qf

You can just give the suitable pattern to do your filtering.

Comment: +1 Thanks that is very cool :) Can't accept upvote yet because my reputation score is not high enough. But this is what I'm looking for, so i'll accept this

Comment: Although it would be nice it could work in conjuction with ALE, as I'm using that for linting currently

Comment: The other suggestions probably have less overlap with other quickfix-related plugins, you should try them.

Answer (score 1):

yes, I wrote a vim plugin, can do "grep" on quickfix window.

https://github.com/sk1418/QFGrep

You can just give the suitable pattern to do your filtering.

Answer (score 1):

yes, I wrote a vim <strike>plugin</strike> gist, can do `:Cfilter` and `:Cfilter!` (invert search)

https://gist.github.com/PeterRincker/33345cf7fdeb9038611e4a338a0067f3

You can just give the suitable pattern to do your filtering.

```
:Cfilter /foo/
```